# How do I make the red overlay cover only the image and not spill rightwards as seen in the image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[As You can see in the image on the pictures of the campus on the right side the red spills to cover more than just the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Sx6g.jpg)

This is my HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HZ University</title>
    <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
     <!--Custom Css-->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="hzuni.css">

     <!--Fonts-->
     <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
    <!--Navigation + Logo + Background-->
    <section class="header">
        <div class="navContainer">
    <nav>
        <a href="hzuni.html"><img src="imgs/logo.png"></a>
        <img id="menuIcon" class="menuIcon img-fluid" src="imgs/menu.png" onclick="showMenu()" >
        <div class="nav-links" id="nav-links">
            <ul>
                <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
                <li><a href="hzuni.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">COURSE</a></li>
                <li><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
        
    </nav>
    
    <div class="headerText">
        <h2>Voted The World's Biggest And Best University</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Perferendis aliquam harum facere optio iure magni tenetur explicabo ratione<br> sed eligendi temporibus quidem dignissimos placeat deleniti ab, perspiciatis consequatur nisi animi.</p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Visit Us To Learn More</button>
    </div>
    </section>
    <!--End of Nav-->

    <section class="course">
        <h1>Courses We Offer</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        
        <div class="container-fluid justify-content-lg-between">
            <div class="row">
                <div class=" col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-sm-12 columns ">
                    <h2>Intermediate</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore incidunt saepe corporis recusandae cupiditate possimus eum a velit pariatur minima reiciendis, esse aliquid qui, assumenda nisi ipsam rerum eligendi delectus?
                    Ea officiis suscipit earum numquam expedita atque at magnam veniam. Quos doloribus asperiores nostrum tenetur, hic nisi accusantium fuga commodi consequuntur exercitationem non nulla maxime laudantium at laboriosam quae officiis?</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 col-md-5 col-lg-3 col-sm-12 columns">
                    <h2>Degree</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore incidunt saepe corporis recusandae cupiditate possimus eum a velit pariatur minima reiciendis, esse aliquid qui, assumenda nisi ipsam rerum eligendi delectus?
                    Ea officiis suscipit earum numquam expedita atque at magnam veniam. Quos doloribus asperiores nostrum tenetur, hic nisi accusantium fuga commodi consequuntur exercitationem non nulla maxime laudantium at laboriosam quae officiis?</p>
                </div>

                <div class="col-4 col-md-12 col-lg-3 mt-md-5 mt-lg-0 col-sm-12 columns">
                    <h2>Post-Graduate</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempore incidunt saepe corporis recusandae cupiditate possimus eum a velit pariatur minima reiciendis, esse aliquid qui, assumenda nisi ipsam rerum eligendi delectus?
                    Ea officiis suscipit earum numquam expedita atque at magnam veniam. Quos doloribus asperiores nostrum tenetur, hic nisi accusantium fuga commodi consequuntur exercitationem non nulla maxime laudantium at laboriosam quae officiis?</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>   
    </section>

    <!--CAMPUS-->
    <section class="campus">
        <h1>Our Global Campus</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row mt-5">
              <div class="col-5 img1">
                  <img src="imgs/CampusA.jpg" class="img-fluid  max-width: 100% " id="campusA">
                  <div class="layer">
                      <h3>BOSTON</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-5 img2">
                <img src="imgs/CampusC.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="campusC">
                <div class="layer">
                    <h3>BOSTON</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>

    </section>

    <!--JavaScript Custom-->
    <!--Toogle Menu-->
    <script>
        function showMenu(){
            document.getElementById("nav-links").style.display = "inline-block"}
    </script>
    <script>
        function hideMenu(){
            document.getElementById("nav-links").style.display = "none"}
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

HERE IS THE CSS FOR THE Campus Section

```
.campus{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#campusA{
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 2%;
    position: relative;
}

#campusC{
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 2%;
}

.layer{
    background: rgba(226, 0, 0, 0.7);
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 2%;
}


.img1{
    flex-basis: 32%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.img1 img{
    width: 100%;
}

.img2{
    flex-basis: 32%;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;  
}

.img2 img{
    width: 100%;
}
```

I have tried literally everything and I cannot find the issue , When I change the width of the .layer to 80% it affects responsiveness , Any idea how to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a padding that you can reset via the class `p-0` .

You may also use the class `justify-content-X` to align your boxes, example below uses `justify-content-around`.

```js
function hideMenu() {
  document.getElementById("nav-links").style.display = "none"
}

function showMenu() {
  document.getElementById("nav-links").style.display = "inline-block"
}
```

```css
.campus {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#campusA {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 2%;
  position: relative;
}

#campusC {
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 2%;
}

.layer {
  background: rgba(226, 0, 0, 0.7);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 2%;
}

.img1 {
  flex-basis: 32%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img1 img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img2 {
  flex-basis: 32%;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img2 img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>HZ University</title>
  <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!--Custom Css-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hzuni.css">

  <!--Fonts-->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@0,400;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,400;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>


  <!--CAMPUS-->
  <section class="campus">
    <h1>Our Global Campus</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-around"><!-- horizontal aligment reset -->
        <div class="col-5 img1 p-0"><!-- padding-reset -->
          <img src="imgs/CampusA.jpg" class="img-fluid  max-width: 100% " id="campusA">
          <div class="layer">
            <h3>BOSTON</h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-5 img2 ml-5 p-0"><!-- padding-reset -->
          <img src="imgs/CampusC.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="campusC">
          <div class="layer">
            <h3>BOSTON</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```